# Android Studio Project Structure screen looks broken

Tags: android-studio

I am migrating a project to the latest android studio and the project structure screen looks rather broken. E.g. I need to configure the usage of Gooogle APIs API Level 19 and cannot do that.... how could I fix that? Could it be my project contains some broken android studio metadata or so?

[image: broken android studio screen]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `Project Structure` to look fine. This is the latest Android Studio (0.5.4).
[image]

---

When you click on `Modules` tab you should be able to change to the latest SDK.

[image]